# How can I edit an exe stub with C#?

Tags: c#

How can I take a comilied exe stub, coded something like this
string x="Hi";
Console.WriteLine(x);

and modify it from another c# program(e.g. change the value of x)

Comment: I won't be able to answer this,  but I'm curious, what is an "exe stub"? (Just trying to learn.)

Comment: You want to recompile the exe or just modify in memory the value of x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to to compile string of code dynamically on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is [signed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or has a [strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx), you cannot modify it without having access to the private key. Otherwise the tampering will be evident.

Assuming that the parameter is not stored outside the executable, such as in the registory or an app.config file, this is quite difficult. One way could be to look at the IL and use classes in the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) namespace or [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to write out a new EXE.